# Bulk Loading into BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I run a daily report that feeds from 6 files that I then upload into BigQuery, and query it to give me a final file that I distribute to a sales team.

The problem that I'm facing is that it's extremely tedious to create 6 new tables (and then delete them, due to security policies) every day.

I know that one of the possibilities is to query straight from a google sheets file, but the organization that I work for isn't too keen on storing our documents in a Google Server. If that truly is the only way, I may be able to knock on that door again, but I'd rather not.

I want to bulk upload all the .csv files, get different names (that correspond to the .csv name) and run my queries.

Would that be possible?

Comment: You could upload the file to google storage (GCS) and use create in BigQuery "external" tables to these files. The delete after the upload, sounds not to be the best security solution. Depending on the file size, a local python script for merging could be the better solution.

Comment: Does BigQuery auto identify the schema when they are loaded into buckets?

Comment: The schema for external tables is autodetected if you create or replace the (external) table in BigQuery. Adding csv-files in the gcs does not start the autodetect again.

Answer (score 0):

According to @Samuel:

You could upload the file to Google Cloud Storage (GCS) and use create in BigQuery "external" tables to these files. The delete after the upload, sounds not to be the best security solution. Depending on the file size, a local python script for merging could be the better solution

Posting this answer as a Community Wiki since this serves as a workaround and for the benefit of the community that might encounter this use case in the future.

Please feel free to edit this answer for additional information and if there are other possible workarounds/direct solutions for this use case.